# Would total annihilation of Humanity cause Nirvana for everyone?

Tags: nirvana, death, samsara, human

If nirvana is to escape the cycle of Samsara, wouldn't all of humanity being dead meaning Samsara would end? Say there was a total nuclear war and everyone ends up dead.

Comment: No,in my opinion annihilation of 'human-ness' will.

Comment: Vladimir, is it you? Bad joke aside, see the answer of Desmon.

Comment: Yes, @Desmon is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The human realm is only one of the [thirty one planes of existence](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sagga/loka.html) mentioned in Buddhist sutras. If all of humanity is wiped out, we will likely end up in the other realms. Even when a world cycle ends i.e. the end of the universe, there are some realms that are not affected by the subsequent destruction and rebirth of the universe. So, the cycle of samsara never ends or stops temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

No, the total annihilation of humanity is not considered a path to Nirvana in traditional spiritual teachings. Nirvana is seen as an individual, spiritual achievement, and promoting harm or destruction conflicts with ethical principles in many belief systems.